# Calling removeFromSuperview() from deinit

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

The following code doesn't seem to work for me.

```
class SomeSubView: UIView {

    deinit {
        removeFromSuperview()
    }

}


let view = UIView()

var subview: SomeSubView! = SomeSubView()
var subview2: SomeSubView! = SomeSubView()

view.addSubview(subview)
view.addSubview(subview2)

subview = nil
subview = SomeSubView()
view.addSubview(subview)

print(view.subviews) //contains three views, should contain two
```

I also had a `print()` inside the deinit, so I'm pretty sure it is called. I could call `subview.removeFromSuperview()` before making the expression `subview = nil`, that works fine.

I'm only curious why this limitation exists, what kind of stuff can not be done inside `deinit`? I feel what I'm trying to do should work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never necessary to call `removeFromSuperview()` on `self` in `deninit`. A superview retains its subviews, so it's impossible for a view to be deallocated while it is a subview.

Setting `subview = nil` does not deallocate the object referenced by `subview`. It simply stops making `subview` reference that object.